# How Do I Delete All Posts Over 400 Days Old

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have tried the following phpMyAdmin query in an effort to delete all posts from database category 378 that are over 400 days old.

```
DELETE a,b,c,d
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id )
WHERE e.term_id =378 AND DATEDIFF( NOW(), a.post_date ) > 400
```

Instead, the query seems to have deleted that entire category and all its posts. How do I make a phpMyAdmin query that will just delete any posts over 400 days old from that particular category?

I do have database backups.

Comment: No point in deleting old posts especially in a wordpress site it's all indexed by google and it will harm your website with broken links on google search engine, since you won't be able to find your website on the first page google anymore.

Comment: @SSpoke, the site has over 300,000 posts. Other circumstances make it, more or less, necessary that I delete a significant percentage of them.

Comment: So posts barely take any space on the harddrive biggest post might hit 1 KB at most. I'm guessing all images are hotlinked anyways if uploaded that's another problem. It doesn't really slow down the database if you have alot of tables. Not mention if you make money from your site when people search for something and won't find it in that location anymore they won't like that haha.

Comment: I guess my particular situation differs from what you have in mind, because my frequently optimized mysql database of > 300,000 posts is over 1 gigabyte in size, as opposed to 300,000kb.

Comment: did you try to optimize the mysql tables command might improve that.

Comment: In my previous comment I did specify "my frequently optimized mysql database".

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
WHERE date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 400 DAY))
```

Comment: If the following is what you mean: `delete a,b,c,d
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id )
WHERE date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 400 DAY))` How do I specify the category from which I want to delete all posts over 400 days old?

Comment: When I tried to select those posts, using the code you provided, I got an "Unknown column date in where clause" error message.